# how to find log4j version in azure databricks notebook

Tags: log4j, databricks, azure-databricks

Any command to run on "python" notebook of azure databricks environment.I have tried below as per databricks document but it is giving error.

```py
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Version
println(Version.getProductString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Versions of all libraries included into Databricks Runtime are listed in the [Databricks Runtime Release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases) - if you select specific runtime version, you can find all necessary information. For example, if you open release notes for [DBR 10.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/10.1), then you will see that it uses log4j 1.2.17.

You can find more information about log4j vulnerability and Databricks in a separate [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/12/13/log4j2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-research-and-assessment.html) that is updated regularly.  You can contact email provided in the blog post to get more clarifications.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your constant support!!